# Beautiful Soup is Missing Tables from Wikipedia

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, html-table

I am trying to get the La Liga League Table from [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/2015%E2%80%9316_La_Liga), but I can't even seem to use `find_all` to even get to the table I'm trying to scrape.  Moreover, the exact same code I wrote scrapes the EPL data from wikipedia perfectly fine...

The full HTML is here: view-source:https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/2015%E2%80%9316_La_Liga

The part in question is here:

```html
<h2><span class="mw-headline" id="League_table">League table</span><span class="mw-editsection"><span class="mw-editsection-bracket">[</span><a href="/w/index.php?title=2015%E2%80%9316_La_Liga&amp;action=edit&amp;section=6" title="Edit section: League table">edit</a><span class="mw-editsection-bracket">]</span></span></h2>
<h3><span class="mw-headline" id="Standings">Standings</span><span class="mw-editsection"><span class="mw-editsection-bracket">[</span><a href="/w/index.php?title=2015%E2%80%9316_La_Liga&amp;action=edit&amp;section=7" title="Edit section: Standings">edit</a><span class="mw-editsection-bracket">]</span></span></h3>
<table class="wikitable" style="text-align:center;">
  <tr>
    <th scope="col" width="28"><abbr title="Position">Pos</abbr>
    </th>
    <th scope="col" width="190">Team
      <div class="plainlinks hlist navbar mini" style="float:right">
        <ul>
          <li class="nv-view"><a href="/wiki/Template:2015%E2%80%9316_La_Liga_table" title="Template:2015–16 La Liga table"><span title="View this template">v</span></a>
          </li>
          <li class="nv-talk"><a href="/wiki/Template_talk:2015%E2%80%9316_La_Liga_table" title="Template talk:2015–16 La Liga table"><span title="Discuss this template">t</span></a>
          </li>
          <li class="nv-edit"><a class="external text" href="//en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Template:2015%E2%80%9316_La_Liga_table&amp;action=edit"><span title="Edit this template">e</span></a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </th>
```

This is how I request the page and my only cleansing of the code before I try to find all of the tables:

```
soup = BeautifulSoup(requests.get("https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/2015-16_La_Liga").text, "html.parser")
for superscript in soup.find_all("sup"):
    superscript.decompose()
print len(soup.find_all("table", attrs={"class": "wikitable"}))
```

However I am getting a length of 2 when looking at the page html, I should be getting at least 14 tables with those attributes...

I have no idea where to go from here, any help would be appreciated

--EDIT--

[image: Input/Output]
[image: Output of soup shows that the wikitable is still there...]

Comment: Please provide a short, **complete** program that demonstrates the problem. When I fix the errors in your program, [the resulting program](http://pastebin.com/kCgcHvJV) prints `13` for me.

Comment: I don't need help with that.  When I run what you have in pastebin, which I already posted, I get an output of 2

Comment: So we have a mystery. Why do *you* get 2, while I get 13? Perhaps you could examine `requests.get().text` and see if it includes all of the tables.

Comment: @Robᵩ it does I can post an image if needed

Comment: @qwertylpc - what version of Python are you using? (You can get that by `print sys.version`).

Comment: I get the same result as OP with the same code. I also checked using regular expressions how many wikitables there are in the soup: More than just two. No idea what’s going on though.

Comment: @Robᵩ 2.7.10 |Anaconda 2.3.0 (64-bit)| (default, May 28 2015, 16:44:52) [MSC v.1500 64 bit (AMD64)]

Comment: @Dunes I am using requests and not urllib3.  Also the string is there...

Comment: urllib3 [is](http://www.python-requests.org/en/latest/) embedded within requests

Answer (score 1):

Everything work fine.

PyQuery version

```
from pyquery import PyQuery

pq = PyQuery(url="https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/2015-16_La_Liga")
all_tables = pq(".wikitable")
print len(all_tables)
```

BeautifulSoup version

```
__author__ = "Leonard Richardson (leonardr@segfault.org)"
__version__ = "4.3.2"
__copyright__ = "Copyright (c) 2004-2013 Leonard Richardson"
__license__ = "MIT"

from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests



soup = BeautifulSoup(requests.get("https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/2015-16_La_Liga").text, "html.parser")
for superscript in soup.find_all("sup"):
    superscript.decompose()
print len(soup.find_all("table", attrs={"class": "wikitable"}))
```

return 13 both version

Maybe you should install 4.3.2 version of bs or use PyQuery?

Comment: I'm running bs 4.4.0, I will try 4.3.2

Comment: Try [pyquery](https://pythonhosted.org/pyquery/) he has simple and powerfull css selectors.

Answer (score 0):

```
from urllib.request import urlopen
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
html = urlopen('https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/2015-16_La_Liga')
bsObj = BeautifulSoup(html.read(), 'lxml')
result = bsObj.find_all("table", class_="wikitable")
print (result)
```

But this got only 13 tables which i actually saw on the url 
i used

```
python==3.4.3
beautifulsoup4==4.4.1
```

also you might want to install requests using `pip install requests`